# Complete the week based on minimum week for each name to the current week

Tags: r

I have a Dataframe like below. I want to fill in week and year for each name based on the first week. What I am looking for is just minimum week of each name and the fill all the way until the most recent week of the most recent year.

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("John", 
"Mary"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2020L, 2021L
), Week = c(1L, 5L, 3L, 5L), Total = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Desired output

```
Name Year Week Total
John 2021 1 3
John 2021 2 0
John 2021 3 0
John 2021 4 0
John 2021 5 1
Mary 2020 3 1
Mary 2020 4 0
Mary 2020 5 0
.
.
.
Mary 2021 4 0
Mary 2021 5 2
```

My code:

```
data %>%
  complete(Week = seq(min(Week), 53), fill = list(Total = 0))
  fill(c(Name, year))
```

Comment: Probably adding `group_by(Name, Year) %>%` after `data %>%` and remove the `fill` statement will work.

Comment: So If the first week for Mary is 3rd week of 2020 then I want data to be completed all the way until 5th week of 2021. So all weeks of 2020 and all weeks of 2021 until the 5th week.

Comment: I edited my answer according to your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to convert your date into a year-week format and to do a sequence over it. I'm using `tsibble` to do that.

```
library(tsibble); library(tidyr); library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(date = make_yearweek(Year,Week)) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  complete(date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = 1), fill = list(Total = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(Year = format(date, "%G"), Week = format(date, "%V"))

   Name      date Year  Week  Total
   <fct>   <week> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 John  2021 W01 2021  01        3
 2 John  2021 W02 2021  02        0
 3 John  2021 W03 2021  03        0
 4 John  2021 W04 2021  04        0
 5 John  2021 W05 2021  05        2
 6 Mary  2020 W03 2020  03        1
 7 Mary  2020 W04 2020  04        0
 8 Mary  2020 W05 2020  05        0
 9 Mary  2020 W06 2020  06        0
10 Mary  2020 W07 2020  07        0
```